# Database authentication in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Can anyone explain me what difference does spring security authentication way makes than authenticating user directly by checking if username and password exist from database(which is lot less complicated).

And how to do database user authentication using spring security? The online tutorials are really complex(with 100's line of code directly without any high level explanation) and I'm new in spring boot, I'm unable to follows there steps.

So please can anyone tell me each step that are required for authentication in easy language and reasons for that and how it is different from checking directly if username and password exist without using spring security. I'm having hard time grasping these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

If by 100's of lines of code, you are meaning to say the different configurations that are required, then there is no bypass to that. All Spring technologies work on a layer of abstraction over core libraries but to use that some of the configurations are required.

The purpose of UsernamePassword authentication in Spring Security is not limited to a normal authentication but to make your application's authorization work on based on the results it get from authentication. It is basically role based security at the front of all your requests.

The simplest tutorial I have found is http://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_security_jdbc_authentication